# document.pages is empty when sending a DocumentAI batch process documents request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, cloud-document-ai

I'm using the following Google sample code to do the batch process of DocumentAI OCR:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/documentai/snippets/batch_process_documents_sample.py

Instead of `print(document.text)`, I was trying to use `document.pages` to get all the lines, but this returns an empty list (`document.text` is not empty).

Comment: Thanks. After I change the field_mask to  `text,pages.layout,pages.lines`, it works.